# Issue in Connecting ADF to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect to snowflake using Azure Data Factory using Self-hosted integration run time. I am getting the below error. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL  failed:
> CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=35 msg='SSL connect
> error' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.

Comment: Check this [soution](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/CURLerror-SSL-peer-certificate-or-SSH-remote-key-was-not-OK-during)

Comment: Snowflake is maintained by another vendor, so I can't run these commands. Before reaching out to them is there anything I need to check from the ADF side?

Comment: @Rathesh The issue appears because some of the Snowflake endpoints are not reachable. Some of them are unique for a Snowflake account. Therefore, you need to contact a Snowflake admin and get them running select system$allowlist(); command and share the result with your azure network admin. The listed URLs must be allowed with the respective ports on your azure "firewall".

Answer (score 0):

ERROR [ HY000 ] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=35 msg='SSL connect error' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.

Make sure to add IP address of Self hosted Integration runtime server to the allowed list in Snowflake.   Below are the recommendations to avoid this error from Snowflake.

> - Make sure to bypass the endpoints found from `SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST`  [0] and `SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST_PRIVATELINK` [1].
> - Bypass the S3 bucket URL [the ones that are seen in the error stack of the error thrown ].

Refer [CURLerror 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' using ODBC driver connection to Snowflake- Snowflake documention](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/CURLerror-SSL-peer-certificate-or-SSH-remote-key-was-not-OK-during) for more details.

[0] [SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST | Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist)

[1] [SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST_PRIVATELINK | Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist_privatelink)

Comment: Where do I need to run these command?

Comment: Connect to snowflake through WebUI and execute `SELECT SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST();` Refer the attached documentation [system$allowlist](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist) and [system$allowlist_privatelink](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist_privatelink) in the answer for more details.

Comment: I don't have any access to Web UI as of now. For connecting through Web UI, my machine IP needs to be whitelisted. But they won't do that. The only way I can access the data is through ADF and that is not working

Comment: Check if the IP address of the system where SHIR is installed is whitelisted. Without that you can't access thru ADF

Comment: Is Self hosted integration run time need to be used or Auto resolve integration time?

Comment: Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites)